# A boundary-preserving map on the unit disk

Tags: gn.general-topology, fa.functional-analysis

We are given a (closed) ball $D^n$ and a (continuous) map $f: D^n \to D^n$, that is identity on the boundary of $D^n$.

Let $C$ be a subset of $D^n$, and let $f^{-1}(C)$ be the inverse image of $C$ in $D^n$.

The claim is that there exists a map $g: C \to f^{-1}(C)$ that is identity on the intersection of $C$ and the boundary of $D^n$.

I actually suspect that the claim is wrong in general, but cannot find a counter-example. Also, if it is indeed wrong, what are the conditions on $C$ and $f$ so that it is correct?

Comment: I edited your post so that the maths works. Have a look at the source (by clicking 'edit') to see what I did.

Comment: You probably require $g$ to be continuous...

Comment: Sure, all maps here are continuous.

Comment: I've spent some time thinking about it and there are probably a lot of different cases to study (If I am not missing something). Can you specify what you are looking for, or do you really need the answer in its most general form?

Comment: My idea is the following: (I haven't checked all details and am thus not entirely sure)  $f$ induces a map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ and for the homotopy class we have $[f]\in \mathbb Z$. Since $f$ is the identity on the boundary, $f$ must in fact be homotopic to the identity. Thus we have a map $H: D^n\times I\rightarrow D^n$, which is the identity on the bottom and $f$ on the top. For $C\subset D^n$, we may now consider $H^{-1}(C)$, which is $f^{-1}(C)$ on the top and $C$ on the bottom. Now we should somehow be able to use the pathes in $H^{-1}(C)$ to construct $g$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we know that paths in $H^{-1}(C)$ induce a continuous map? Unfortunately, I am not sure I can specify additional conditions on C and f to make it simpler.

Comment: Take $B$ to be the union of $a\sin\frac{\pi}x$ ('$0<x\le 1$'), interval from $-1$ to $0$ and the interval from $-ia$ to $ia$ on the complex plane. Now take any continuous map $f$ that is identity on the boundary, sends $[-ia,ia]$ to one point and doesn't glue any other two points together. Put $C=f(B)$. Then $C$ is a continuous path from $-1$ to $1$ but $B=f^{-1}(C)$ contains no such path.

Comment: @fedja: Just to make sure I understand. You consider $D^2$ (radius $1$?) on the complex plan, and define B as the union of the interval $[-1,0]$ on the x axis, $[-ia,ia]$ on the y axis and a collection of points $a\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$ on the x axis. How you choose $a$? In $(0,1)$? Two questions: (1) Why exactly $f(B)=[-1,1]$? (2) Why is $f$ continuous? Thanks!

Comment: You can take $a=0.1$, say. It is there just to make the curve stay inside the unit disk. And I meant the curve $x\mapsto x+ia\sin\frac{\pi}x$, of course (what I wrote is ambiguous). $f(B)$ is not $[-1,1]$ but a (=some) continuous path joining $-1$ and $1$. $f$ is continuous because I choose it so. I didn't specify what exactly it is but you can easily imagine a vertical rubber band through $(x,0)$ with ends on the circle with two points glued to your thumb and your index finger, which you slowly bring together as x runs from -1 to 0 and then back apart as you go from 0 to 1.

Comment: @fedja: Just to summarize.

$B$ is the curves $x+ia\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$ ($x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$), and the interval $[-ia,ia]$. 

You select $f$ to be any continuous boundary preserving map such that $f$ collapses the interval $[-ia,ia]$ to $0$ and otherwise it does not send any two points to one point.  

Now $f(B)$ is indeed a curve connecting $-1$ and $1$ and $f^{-1}([-1,1])$ is $B$. 

But there is no continuous map from $[-1,1]$ to $B$, that is identity at $-1$ and $1$ - QED

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, last two $[-1,1]$ must be some fixed curve from $-1$ to $1$, of course.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Need to think what to assume to get rid of such "exotic" counter-examples (sine curves is not something I would call natural:)). Also, should I post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a real mess, due to all the posts by Petr before he figured out about comments. But if you read it through carefully, fedja has provided an answer, which I am copying here so this question will stop being bumped to the front page. The point is that **the answer is no**. We'll produce a set $C$ which will be a counterexample.

We start by defining a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $A = [-1,0) \cup (0,1] \subset \mathbb{C}$. Fix a real number $0 < a < 1$, and consider the curve $x\mapsto x+ia\sin(\pi/x)$. Because $0 < a < 1$, we know this curve stays inside the unit disk. Define

$$B = \cup_{x \in A} (x+ia\sin(\pi/x)) \cup [−ia,ia]$$

Now take any continuous map $f$ that is identity on the boundary, sends $[−ia,ia]$ to one point (zero, for instance), and otherwise doesn't send any two points to one point (i.e. is injective away from $[-ia,ia]$). It is easy to construct such an $f$. Put $C=f(B)$. Then $C$ is a continuous path from $−1$ to $1$ but $B=f^{-1}(C)$ contains no such path, i.e. there is no continuous map $g$ from $[-1,1]$ to $B$ which is the identity at $-1$ and $1$. Therefore the claim is false.

Comment: Now I hope Petr comes back and deletes his answers which should have been comments. Then this will whole thread will look much better to future viewers. But at least this way, the answer will be clear.